# How can I use CKEditor 5 classic in VueJS 2 WITHOUT NPM?

Tags: vuejs2, ckeditor5

My question is simple. I'm using VueJS 2, and I want to implement CKEditor 5 Classic. I know better than to just hook it up in HTML, but due to constraints I can NOT use NPM/Webpack. I need a component wrapper that's in JS format.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "I know better than to just hook it up in HTML"? After all, the files are included in your HTML anyways, that's how HTML works with JavaScript.

The best option is to use the corresponding [source-file from CDN of CKEditor](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/25.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js). Either by including the direct CDN link or (in case you have doubts about availability) after you download them manually or via shell and ship them with your application.

If you don't want to go one of these ways, I don't think you'll be able to use the desired library at all.

Comment: I know how to use it with HTML. With Vue, they want you to use their connector through NPM. I can't do that. I need a solution that allows me to manipulate the instance without it.

Comment: Hi @Michael, could you please be a little bit more precise on what to achieve and what your restrictions are? When I search for "npm" in [Vue's Guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html) I find 3 occurrences, all three regarding download. I mentioned that you of course may [download the sources from CDN](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/25.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js) (inspect the link).
Since then there is no npm left - **what are you missing, what's still unclear**? E.g., what is "manipulating the instance", you want to edit source?

Comment: I'm using Vue from CDN. I'm also using Ckeditor from JS. I want to bind the value from my CKEditor to my Vue instance like with v-model. But it doesn't work that way. I need a two-way bind. The only information I'm able to find on connecting the two requires NPM/Webpack to do. This is not an option for me.

Comment: Hey @Michael, since I still don't get what's your issue, how about [what I made up here using Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sc1a2hcwp14ehymC)? It uses CKEditor, it uses Vue 3, it has two buttons that show you that two-way data-bindung works.
No npm there, neither webpack. The only file I manually copied is `vue-comp.js`.